# Diagonals of product with commutation matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $K(n,n)$ be a commutation matrix and $\otimes$ denote the Kronecker product. Is there a fast way to compute the diagonal entries of the following:
$K(A\otimes B)$?

Without $K$, $diag(A\otimes B) = diag(A)\otimes diag(B)$. But I am not sure about $diag(K(A\otimes B))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagonal of $K(A\otimes B)$ is $\operatorname{vec}(A\circ B^T)$ (here $\circ$ denotes Hadamard product), because
\begin{aligned}
\langle K(A\otimes B)E_{ij},\,E_{ij}\rangle
&=\langle K(A\otimes B)(e_j\otimes e_i),\,e_j\otimes e_i\rangle\\
&=\langle K(a_{\ast j}\otimes b_{\ast i}),\,e_j\otimes e_i\rangle\\
&=\langle b_{\ast i}\otimes a_{\ast j},\,e_j\otimes e_i\rangle\\
&=\langle b_{\ast i},e_j\rangle \langle a_{\ast j},e_i\rangle\\
&=b_{ji}a_{ij}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thanks so much!